# How do i download actual resolution/size images from chrome?

Tags: photoshop

Whenever i download an higher resolution image chrome compresses it to around 100kb .What can i do to solve this? Is there a certain `setting` in chrome?

Comment: AFAIK chrome does not actually compresses images. Maybe the website contains high resolution images, but makes available only compressed versions of it.

Answer (score -1):

Try clicking on the image, then long press and choose open image in new tab. This should give you a good idea of how big the image is. Then long press and save the image. Note: the mobile version of Google Images does have search tools too (its at the extreme right in the bar with tabs for web, images, videos etc.)